# Reading and Writing from IO pins in C on MPLab X IDE

Tags: c, mplab, pic32

I recently started work with a PIC32MX764F128H microcontroller, I'm used to doing things on PIC18 and PIC24.. . AKA using CCS C compiler, So I am curious if anyone knows how to do some really basic C code for a 32bit chip in MPLab X. I just want the code to take the input from An analog pin and put the opposite value in an output pin.

For example if PIN_B0 is input and I have a 3.3v plugged into it (this chip uses 3.3 not 5v) I'd like to read PIN_C0 as 0v, but if PIN_B0 is grounded I'd like PIN_C0 to read a high signal of 3.3v

I'm very rusty at this on such a low level application and cannot remember how to do so in C.
Below is some of what I have so far in C but it isn't compiling and MPLab is awful at assisting in code issues.

```
#fuses HS,NOLVP,NOWDT,PUT
int main()
{
   TRISB=0;//all of Port B is input
   TRISC=1;//all of Port C is output
   int RecvInput;
   while(true)
   {
      RecvInput = ??? //how do I get from Pin_B0 ??
      if(Recv==0)
      {
         //HOW DO I SAY PIN_C0 = HIGH
      }
      else //PIN_C0 = 0
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RecvInput = mPORTBRead();
```

Then to output:

```
mPORTBWrite(value);
```

Comment: `error maincCode.c:30: undefined reference to 'input_b'`.... I missing a header or something?

Comment: @DarthSheldon do you import the header for your chip?

Comment: MPLab X v1.92 just installed it clean

Comment: Try adding something like `#include <18F8722.h>` but use the model number for your chip.

Comment: @DarthSheldon you could try: `mPORTBRead()`

Comment: looks like that was accepted by MPLabX thanks! change your answer and I'll give you the checkmark